# Verify OS X Base System

Tags: macos, mac-pro, internet-recovery

Mac Pro (Late 2013) macOS Mavericks

Internet Recovery Mode:

OS X Utilities:

```
Disk Utility:

    disk0

      OS X Base System
```

I can verify "OS X Base System" but not erase, restore or alter partition layout?

Comment: No problem, I appreciate any input as I have been struggling with this problem for quite some time now.

Comment: @Anthony Mendez Is this a more or less educational question just to understand what it's use for? It might be helpful to explain the background of your question in some more detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

macOS Internet Recovery is a NetBoot-like service. Basically, a bootable image is downloaded via HTTP (from an Apple or an Akamai server) into RAM and your Mac boots to it afterwards.

So yes, you can run **First Aid** on the **OS X Base System** *volume* and it will not erase, restore or alter partition layout because it's not a writable *volume*.

---

Since it has to be assumed that the image was verifed already after the download has finished and the boot process was successful, why do you want to verify the **OS X Base System** again?